# unused argument (key = "iris.hex")

Tags: r, file-upload, key, h2o

When ever I try to run this line or any other line which uses key(following document in http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-lambert/5/docs-website/Ruser/rtutorial.html)

```
iris.hex = h2o.uploadFile(localH2O, path = irisPath, key = "iris.hex")
```

I get an error in the key calling it as unused argument.

This is the first time I am using H2O and I am new to R as well. Please let me know what is the function of key and only when I run this, I get error. I could create a dataframe with the following statement. But still I would want to understand this key error

```
h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH2O = TRUE)
irisPath = system.file("extdata", "iris.csv", package = "h2o")
iris.hex = h2o.uploadFile(path = prosPath, destination_frame = "iris.hex")
iris.data.frame<- as.data.frame(iris.hex)
summary(iris.data.frame)
```

Comment: looking at the current documentation for H2O, uploadFile does not take an argument named key.  Most likely, the tutorial you are trying to follow is either wrong, or based on an earlier version of H2O.

Comment: The tutorial that you're looking at is for h2o version 2; whilst you probably have h2o version 3 installed. You can see that the tutorial is based on version 2, because the [R Package Documentation](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-lambert/5/docs-website/Ruser/Rpackage.html) links to version 2.6.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very outdated version of the H2O docs and there have been some major API changes since H2O 3.0.  The latest R docs can always be found at: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_Rdoc.html

Our [main docs landing page](http://www.h2o.ai/docs/) has a link to the latest R docs, Python docs, and a bunch of other links you may find useful.  We also have a Google Group called [h2ostream](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2ostream) for posting new questions and searching through old questions.  Welcome to H2O!

Answer (score 3):

H2O may be very good in various areas. but unfortunately lack of documentation and tutorial makes it's really difficult to learn...

Hoping that they watch these type of comments and improve their documentation.

At least launching one tutorial of 12GB airlines data processing can help a lot for multiple enthusiastic people who really wanted to explore H2O.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).